# Run-time error 1004 when checking for empty values

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

The below sub is not working:

```
Sub RemoveAllBelowStr()
    Dim SrchRng As Range, i As Integer
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A700")
    For i = 0 To SrchRng.rows.Count
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, "A")) Then Exit For 'THIS LINE IS THROWING RUN TIME ERROR
    Next i
    rows(i & ":" & rows.Count).Delete
End Sub
```

I am getting an "Application-defined or object-defined" run-time error 1004.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is: `Cells(i, "A")`

1. You need to qualify what Cells, presumably those of `SrchRange`
2. You need a numeric column index rather than `"A"`
3. It attempts to access row index zero but the first index is 1

so `SrchRng.Cells(i, 1)`

After correcting the index:

```
For i = 1 To SrchRng.Rows.Count
```

As an alternative you could:

```
dim cell as range
For each cell in SrchRng
   if isempty(cell) then ...
```

Comment: it doesn't have to be a numeric index. Cells() works with column letters too.

Answer (score 2):

The loop must start at 1, not 0.